# JQuery Validate Plugin

Tags: jquery, arrays, serialization, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the validate plugin but I guess it's not setup correctly. This is my header:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<title>Registration Page 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#everything").submit( function() {
        var data = $("#everything").serializeArray();
        $("#everything").validate({
            alert(data);
        });
        return true;
    });

});
</script>
</head>
```

But it's not recognizing the validate method so it is not using it. Should I use a different source? Can anyone see any problem?

P.S: Is there anyway to serialize all the data in a form into an array so I can reference it like

```
data["first_name"]
```

I tried the serializeArray and did:

```
alert(data["first_name"]);
```

But it said it was undefined. Anyone know how to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7z55n/)**

```
<form id="commentForm">
  <div><input type="text" name="a" id="a" class='required'/></div>
  <div><input type="text" name="b" id="b" class='required'/></div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" name="g" value="Submit" id="everything" />
  </div>
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate({
     submitHandler: function(form) {
              var dataArray = $("#commentForm").serializeArray();
                 dataObj = {};
                $(dataArray).each(function(i, field){
                  dataObj[field.name] = field.value;
                }); 
                 alert(dataObj['a']);                
         }    
    });            
  });​
```

You can use jquery .each function to iterate over arrays

**[.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)**

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays.